# Transform first column to integers, rest to floats

Tags: python

I have a list of lists (`nLedgers`) such as:

```
[['173', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['183', '1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['184', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['194', '1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['195', '0.', '0.', '1000.'], ['205', '1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['206', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['216', '1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['217', '0.', '0.', '2000.'], ['227', '1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['228', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['238', '1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['239', '0.', '0.', '3000.'], ['249', '1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['250', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['260', '1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['261', '0.', '0.', '4000.'], ['271', '1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['272', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['282', '1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['283', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['293', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['294', '1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['304', '1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['305', '0.', '0.', '1000.'], ['315', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['316', '1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['326', '1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['327', '0.', '0.', '2000.'], ['337', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['338', '1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['348', '1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['349', '0.', '0.', '3000.'], ['359', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['360', '1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['370', '1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['371', '0.', '0.', '4000.'], ['381', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['382', '1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['392', '1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['436', '-1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['446', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['447', '-1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['457', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['458', '-1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['468', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['469', '-1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['479', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['480', '-1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['490', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['491', '-1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['501', '-1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['502', '-1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['512', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['513', '-1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['523', '0.', '0.', '1000.'], ['524', '-1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['534', '0.', '0.', '2000.'], ['535', '-1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['545', '0.', '0.', '3000.'], ['546', '-1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['556', '0.', '0.', '4000.'], ['557', '-1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['567', '-1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['568', '-1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['578', '-1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['579', '-1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['589', '-1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['590', '-1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['600', '-1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['687', '0.', '2000.', '0.'], ['697', '1000.', '2000.', '0.'], ['698', '0.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['708', '1000.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['709', '0.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['719', '1000.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['720', '0.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['730', '1000.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['731', '0.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['741', '1000.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['742', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['752', '0.', '2000.', '0.'], ['753', '1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['763', '1000.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['764', '1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['774', '1000.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['775', '1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['785', '1000.', '2000.', '0.'], ['786', '1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['796', '1000.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['797', '1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['807', '1000.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['808', '-1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['818', '-1000.', '2000.', '0.'], ['819', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['829', '0.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['830', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['840', '0.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['841', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['851', '0.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['852', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['862', '0.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['863', '-1000.', '2000.', '0.'], ['873', '0.', '2000.', '0.'], ['874', '-1000.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['884', '0.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['885', '-1000.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['895', '0.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['896', '-1000.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['906', '0.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['907', '-1000.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['917', '0.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['918', '-1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['928', '-1000.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['929', '-1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['939', '-1000.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['940', '-1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['950', '-1000.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['951', '-1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['961', '-1000.', '2000.', '4000.']]
```

I'd like to transform the first column to integer without the dot sign, and the rest to floats.

I used this code to transform all columns to floats:

```
nLedgers=[[float(j) for j in i] for i in nLedgers]
```

and this to try my goal:

```
nLedgers=[[[if index==0 int(j), if index>0 float(j)] for index,j in i] for i in nLedgers]
```

I've got a syntax error in my code. I think I'm pretty close but I need your help.

Comment: What does it matter to you what the number type is? How will you know the difference ? Are you asking about formatting output, or internal representation?

Comment: @Floris: I then have to compare the value of the first column with the value of another list. So the formats should be the same. I could just change the decimal places but I prefer this solution.

Comment: For fun, you could use `ast.literal_eval`:  `[[literal_eval(x) for x in item] for item in nLedgers]`

Comment: @mgilson: I've got `undefined name ast`. Do I have to import some library?

Comment: Yeah.  put `from ast import literal_eval` in there if you're going to copy/paste the command I put above.

Comment: Thanks! All the replies answer my question but this works 100% as I desired.

Comment: @jpcgandre: "I then have to compare the value of the first column… so the formats should be the same". How does it follow that "the formats should be the same"? What does "the formats" even mean here? Are you converting back to strings before comparing? If so, just format them the way you want; you don't need to convert them to another type to do that.

Comment: @jpcgandre: And if by "formats" you meant "types"… You don't need that either. Python guarantees that you can compare int values to float values, up to a limit of at least 2**53. So `1.0==1` is always true, and so it `173.0==173`. (In fact, `float(2**100)==2**100` is also always true, but unfortunately so is `float(2**100+1)==2**100`.) So, either way, I think you don't need to do anything here.

Comment: @abarnert: Yes, I may have to convert them back to string. Thanks for your explanation. The solution of mgilson is perfect for my purpose.

Comment: @jpcgandre: But you can easily convert float and int values to the same string. For example, look at `'{:.0f}'.format(173.0)` and `'{:.0f}'.format(173)`. It doesn't matter whether you converted it to an `int` or a `float`, you end up with the string `'173'` either way. (Or any other format you want, as long as you know how to specify it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempt is very close. So, while it may not necessarily be the most concise or pythonic way to do this, it will presumably be easy for you to understand.

You've written this:

```
nLedgers=[[[if index==0 int(j), if index>0 float(j)] for index,j in i] for i in nLedgers]
```

---

Your first problem is a `SyntaxError` because that's not how you write [`if` expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions).

And expression that gives you `int(j)` if `index==0`, but otherwise gives you `float(j)`, looks like this:

```
int(j) if index==0 else float(j)
```

Almost a direct translation from English.

---

Your next problem is that you're trying to do `for index, j in i`, which won't work, because `i` is just a sequence of `j` values, not a sequence of pairs of indexes and `j` values.

But the built-in [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) function is meant for exactly this purpose: it converts a sequence of values into a sequence of index-value pairs. So, just for `for index, j in enumerate(i)`.

---

So, if this code translates everything to float:

```
nLedgers=[[float(j) for j in i] for i in nLedgers]
```

We can first add in the `enumerate` to get all the indices:

```
nLedgers=[[float(j) for index, j in enumerate(i)] for i in nLedgers]
```

And then add in the conditional expression to use those indices:

```
nLedgers=[[(int(j) if index==0 else float(j)) for index, j in enumerate(i)] for i in nLedgers]
```

Answer (score 4):

something like this:

```
In [69]: nLedgers=[['173', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['183', '1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['184', '0.', '1000.', '0.']]

In [70]: [ [int(x[0])] + map(float,x[1:]) for x in nLedgers]
Out[70]: [[173, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [183, 1000.0, 0.0, 0.0], [184, 0.0, 1000.0, 0.0]]
```

or:

```
In [71]: [ [int(x[0])] + [float(y) for y in x[1:]] for x in nLedgers]
Out[71]: [[173, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [183, 1000.0, 0.0, 0.0], [184, 0.0, 1000.0, 0.0]]
```

use `list(map(float,x[1:]))` in case you're using py3x.

Comment: This is correct for python2.x.  For python3.x you need either an additional `list` or a list-comp instead of `map`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for i in range(len(nLedgers)):
    i[0]=int(nLegders[0])
    for j in range(1,len(nLedgers[i])):
        nLedgers[i][j]=float(nLedgers[i][j])
```

this is the answer that you are looking for

Comment: Unless the OP is looking for a `TypeError`, this can't possibly be what he's looking for. Also, do you not know about `enumerate` and how to loop over collections? Finally, the OP is transforming one list into another; you're trying to modify a list in-place. That may not be inappropriate, but it is different, and you should at least mention the difference.